# Get specific Outlook attachment (OLE Automation C++)

Tags: c++, email, outlook, ole

I can't get a specific Outlook (2013) email attachment. I'm working on a little project to learn about MS Office Automation using C++ and I'm testing Outlook automation. In partcular I would like to download a specific email attachment but I can't access to that item. For example, if I have in my inbox an email with 4 attachments I want get the 2nd one.
I tried with this code but the HRESULT returned value from the AutoWrap() method is always not valid:

```
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);

CComPtr<IDispatch> pAttachments; // email attachments
HRESULT hRes = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pOfficeItem, L"Attachments", 0);
if (!result.pdispVal || FAILED(hRes)) return EditorError; // EditorError is an Enum

pAttachments = result.pdispVal;

VariantInit(&result);
hRes = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pAttachments, L"Count", 0);
if (FAILED(hRes)) return EditorError;

int aNumber = result.iVal; // it works, if i have an email with 4 attachments then aNumber is 4
if(aNumber > 0){
  VARIANT attachmentIndex;
  attachmentIndex.vt = VT_I4;
  attachmentIndex.llVal = 0; // I want the 1st attachment

  VariantInit(&result);
  CComPtr<IDispatch> pAttachmentItem;

 hRes = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pAttachments, L"Item", 1, attachmentIndex);
  if (FAILED(hRes)) return EditorError; // here it returns EditorError 
}
... DO SOMETHING ...
```

where AutoWrap() is the method recommended by MS in order to interact with the MS Application (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34998/MS-Office-OLE-Automation-Using-C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remarks:

The Index property is only valid during the current session and can change as objects are added to and deleted from the collection. **The first object in the collection has an Index value of 1.**